# How can I delete all records from a table with squeryl?

Tags: mysql, scala, squeryl

I've looked at ways to use squeryl to delete all records from a table. The only thing I could come up with is

```
myTable.deleteWhere(r => r.id.isNotNull)  //id is the primary key
```

This seems strange and possibly inefficient.

What is the cleanest way to delete all records from a table when using squeryl?

Comment: About effeciency -- it may be true, but why would we need deleting the whole database to be quick? This seems unprobable to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @VasyaNovikov You're right. I'm using it for testing, so I want it to be quick, but then again, I don't need loads of data for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `deleteWhere` clause takes any logical boolean, so you could simply say:

```
myTable.deleteWhere(r => 1 === 1)
```

Which should output the statement:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE 1 = 1
```

If you want to eliminate the where clause automatically, you could try:

```
myTable.deleteWhere(r => 1 === 1.inhibitWhen(true))
```

Which should suppress the where clause altogether.

If you are looking for an even more efficient method and your database supports `TRUNCATE` or another equivalent function, you can get a `java.sql.Connection` from [`org.squeryl.Session`](http://squeryl.org/api/index.html#org.squeryl.Session) and issue the query directly through JDBC. Unfortunately, this would lose some of the type safety Squeryl offers.

Comment: Thanks for the options, very helpful. Strange there is no deleteAll, or delete(everyWhere), or something don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, there are a few functions that I am sometimes surprised do not exist. However, it does function across database systems - so the cause can sometimes lie there. Since you can usually find something that works or execute native SQL - I can usually work around anything that is missing.

Comment: By the way, the inhibitWhen doesn't work on MySQL: [error]     RuntimeException: Exception while executing statement : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
[error] errorCode: 1064, sqlState: 42000
[error] delete from Parser
[error] where

Comment: ""Unfortunately, this would lose some of the type safety Squeryl offers." Given we're doing a table truncate here, what might be the impact of this loss of type safety? (i.e. right now I can't see how type safety comes into it)

Comment: Well, by having everything validated through the compiler, you can avoid errors in the SQL like: `TRUNCTE table` where the misspelling would cause an error. Also, by having the class type you know completely that you have the right table instead of an accidental cut and paste. Granted it is less relevant for the `deleteWhere` clause, it can still be useful.